# I'm in an c# objected oriented class and I have these two simple classes

Tags: c#

I'm in an c# objected oriented class and I have these two simple classes but the output for perimeter and area keeps printing out to zero, I tried two different ways and can't figure it out, probably an easy fix, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
class Rectangle { 

   int width; 
   int length;

   public int perimeter;
   public int area;

    public Rectangle()
    {
        width = 1;
        length = 1;
    }
    public Rectangle(int w, int l)
    {
        set_values(w, l);
    }
    public void set_values(int w, int l)
    {
        width = w;
        length = l;
    }
    public Rectangle get_values()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public void calc_perimeter(int width, int length)
    {
        perimeter = 2 * width + 2 * length;
    }
    public void calc_area(int width, int length)
    {
        area = width * length;
    }
    public void display_values()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Width is {0}, and Lenght is {1}", width, length);
    }
    public void display_perimeter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The perimeter of the rectangle is {0}", perimeter);
    }
    public void display_area()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle is {0}", area);
    }

}

class Circle
{
    double radius;

    public double perimeter;
    public double area;


    public Circle()
    {
        radius = 1;

    }
    public Circle(double r)
    {
        set_values(r);
    }
    public void set_values(double r)
    {
        radius = r;

    }
    public Circle get_values()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public double calc_perimeter(double radius)
    {
        perimeter = 2*Math.PI*radius;
        return perimeter;
    }
    public double calc_area(double radius)
    {
        area = Math.PI*radius*radius;
        return area;
    }
    public void display_values()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Radius is {0}", radius);
    }
    public void display_perimeter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The perimeter of the cirlce is {0}", perimeter);
    }
    public void display_area()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is {0}", area);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that is calling into these classes?

Comment: Have you called calc_perimeter first?

Comment: Note that for both classes the calc_area & calc_perimeter methods probably should have no parameters - they would then be calculating the values for the values set in the fields of the class instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is clearly a homework question, I'm not going to post the complete code in the answer - because if I write the code for you, you will not learn anything from it.
Instead, I'm going to explain, in words, what you've done wrong in your classes and how you should fix it.

The shape's perimeter and area is dependent on the shape's size - the width and length of the rectangle or the radius of the circle.
Therefor, it makes sense to calculate it once the size changes.

Usually, you would use public read only properties to get the perimeter and area - once you do that, you have a choice whether you want to calculate them inside the property getter, meaning every time someone calls them, or if you want to calculate them when setting the size values - which should also be done via properties.
This choice should depend on the frequency of the size changes vs the frequency of the perimeter and area usage - for a homework assignment both options should be good enough, though.

So what you do is something like this (in rectangle):

```
private int width;
public int Width
{
    get {return width;}
    set {width = value; SetSize();}
}

private int height;
public int Height
{
    get {return height;}
    set {height = value, SetSize();}
}

// be sure to also call this method in the constructors!
private void SetSize()
{
    // calculate perimeter and area in here.
}

public int Perimeter {get; private set;}
public int Area {get; private set;}
```